# Can currentFrame and totalFrame be pushed into a for loop in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, for-loop

Okay, long story short I'm not near a compiler, but I need to know if I could write something like

```
for (currentFrame; currentFrame < totalFrames; currentFrame + 19;){
//do some animation
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have an array filled with objects, and every 19 frames, have the next objects in the array do some animation, so would the above be a valid way to do this? If not, could you show me how to do it?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: You cannot do a for cycle over `currentFrame`, you'd better use some kind of enterframe listener, count frames (calls) and once you get 19, reset the counter and make an object in the array do animation.

Comment: Good idea, thanks a bunch I'd up vote you if I had the reputation.     EDIT: turns out i can up vote comments.

Comment: Since this wasn't an answer, upvoting comments is not necessary, and your rep is already 15 which allows upvoting of answers. Also note that using an enter frame listener lets you control every single frame with a single set of code, and lets you avoid MovieClips altogether. I'm about to write an answer using a `Sprite` main and `MovieClip` children, so I can call `gotoAndPlay()` on them to make them animate as you've designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an enter frame listener to count frames. This also allows you to not care about the main MC's timeline (make it 1 frame or use a `Sprite`).

```
var yourArray:Array=[...]; // your array, pre-filled
var nowPlaying:int; // index in the array
var frame:int=0; // the frame counter
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,animateChildren);
function animateChildren(e:Event):void {
    frame++;
    if (frame==19) {
        frame=0; // reset counter
        nowPlaying++; // next item to call play()
        if (nowPlaying==yourArray.length) nowPlaying=0; // loop the array
        // so the first item plays after last item
        var mc:MovieClip=yourArray[nowPlaying] as MovieClip;
        if (mc) mc.gotoAndPlay(1); // play the MC in question
    }
}
```

The code can be safely put into a class file instead of timeline, just separate variables into class vars, `addEventListener()` call into constructor, and function into class function.